# What's the difference between sysfs_create_file() and sysfs_create_group()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

The two functions' prototypes:

```
int sysfs_create_group(struct kobject *kobj, const struct attribute_group *grp)
int sysfs_create_file(struct kobject * kobj, const struct attribute * attr)
```

It seems to me that these two functions will both create attributes under the `kobj->name` directory in `sysfs`. The only difference I can find is, the group func can create a group of attributes in one time as the file func only one attribute.
So are there other deferences？ Or is my understanding of the functions wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the group is just a helper wrapper that makes it easier to manage multiple attributes. You can read about them in section 9 of [this pdf](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/mochel/doc/papers/ols-2005/mochel.pdf).

Comment: Where can I find similar files about the kernel architecture for developers?